# Devkit Update site issues with uses of this.getClass().getClassLoader()

Tags: mule, devkit

We are having a lot of issues with devkit built jars that try to resolve files based on either of these methods:

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(configFile);
InputStream in = IOUtils.getResourceAsStream(configFile, getClass());
```

The project works fine when building and running from the original project that compiles down to the devkit update site(ie the project that is using the devkit archtype and @Connector annotated classes), but when running from a project that uses the devkit update site we get file resolution problems.

I can confirm we have the wanted files in **src/main/resources** or **src/test/resources**.
we are using relative paths for the configFile variable eg **file.propertites**

Comment: The resources in src/test/resources are not packaged with the connector, so you can't use them. Are you having these issues in Studio only or also when deployed on Mule?

Comment: @DavidDossot thanks, We actually don't want to package anything in *main/resources** with the connector, we just want end users to be able to resolve their own **main/resources** stuff when trying to load them from the connector. Eg if in the external project they pass in **foo.properties** as the value for **configFile** , the connector fails to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What may happen is that the classloader where your connector class is loaded is different from the classloader where it is used, preventing the load of the classpath resource.

Try with:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(configFile)
```

Comment: Cool thanks, any ideas where there is multiple class loaders in Mule?